# How to convert metres to centimetres in Monkey C?

Tags: garmin, connectiq, monkeyc

Serious newbie question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere!

I'm trying to convert my height from centimetres to metres in an application for my Garmin device. This is written in Monkey C (very similar to Java and C++ from what I understand).

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
var height = angus.height;
var heightCM = height.format("%0.2f");
```

My height is 175, and so as you might expect, this gives me a result of 175.00

I can't seem to find any resource that tells me how to essentially move a decimal to the left. Any help would be really appreciated.

Here's the documentation on formatting in Monkey C: https://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/Lang/Number.html#format-instance_method

Any explanation on formatting numbers would be great. I'm also attempting to truncate a number, so from 1234567 to 1234, for example. So any information on that would also be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if you're programming a language *similar* to some other languages, you should not really add those other unrelated language tags.

Comment: _I can't seem to find any resource that tells my how to essentially move a decimal to the left!_  ever heard of division?

Comment: As for your problem, have you ever heard about *division*? Think back to basic school math: What happens when you divide a number by `10`? By `100`? By `1000`?

Comment: Hey, yeah I tried dividing it, but then I still get a strange result, for example:

var height = angus.height / 100;

var heightCM = height.format("%0.2f");

That gives me: 1.00

Am I using the wrong formatting?

Comment: The title should be about converting centimetres to metres instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 9):

You should use:

```
var height = angus.height / 100.0;
```